Did God swear in order to express His human nature?
We read in Psalm 110:4 (KJV):

The Lord hath sworn, and will not repent, Thou art a priest for ever after the order of Melchizedek.

Hebrews 6:13-17 gives an explanation on why God swore:

When God made his promise to Abraham, since there was no one greater for him to swear by, he swore by himself, 14 saying, “I will surely bless you and give you many descendants.” 15 And so after waiting patiently, Abraham received what was promised. People swear by someone greater than themselves, and the oath confirms what is said and puts an end to all argument. 17 Because God wanted to make the unchanging nature of his purpose very clear to the heirs of what was promised, he confirmed it with an oath.

One is inclined to conclude that God manifested his Human Nature by making an oath in the way human beings did.
What is the take of Bible scholars of different denominations, on the subject?

What makes you say that God was required to swear??

If God swears by himself then no harm (or disrespect) has been done (or shown) to any party. Nor can anyone require God to do anything at all. For He is God.

Consider rewriting the question to "Why do people swear after Jesus tells us not to in Matthew 5:34-37?" This would address the issue more clearly.

Geremia 44:26 Therefore hear the word of the Lord, all you of Judah who dwell in the land of Egypt: Behold, I have sworn by my great name, says the Lord, that my name shall no more be invoked by the mouth of any man of Judah in all the land of Egypt, saying, ‘As the Lord God lives.’  My original intent was to ask : "  By what did God swear ? " But Geremia is clear enough . Hence the question on why God swore .

The question has now changed drastically into an entirely different question thoroughly negating the answer that was given. This should have been a new question and the previous question left standing. Aside from that this new question totally mis-states the Deity/humanity of Christ and seems to assert a Deity/humanity of God prior to incarnation. What 'human nature' is supposed to have existed before a human nature existed ? ? ?

Your views are well-taken, Nijel J. But, what is your interpretation of Gen 1:26 ?  : " And God said, Let us make man in our image, after our likeness ."

....And why does God say in Ex 34:14 that He is a Jealous God ?

Obligatory, this is my understanding from an Orthodox perspective.

You have presupposed that God was "required" to do something. Obviously this is not the case, God is all powerful and the only things He is obligated to do are the things He has said He would do. (God does not lie)

This is a classic "Stump the priest" question. There are many oaths and swearing in the Bible, but what about Mtt 5:34-37 like you pointed out?

First we should note, that lawful oaths are perfectly valid and practiced in all churches. It is lawful when one soberly calls God to witness to the truth of what they say, or to assure others of their commitment to fulfill a vow.
Examples of people giving lawful oaths are found in Genesis 24, Numbers 30, Deuteronomy 23:21-23, ... In legal disputes as in Exodus 22:11-12 and Numbers 5:19. And ultimately we also have Jesus under oath in Matthew 26:63 ("I adjure (εξορκιζω, which means "I place under oath")
We all see this regularly in the new testament as well. 2 Corinthians 1:23, Romans 1:9, Galatians 1:20...

Then you get to 1 Timothy 1:10 where we talk about "false swearers" (Perjurers). As well as Exodus 20:7 (do not take the Name of the Lord in Vain)

God then also swears oaths, Deuteronomy 7:8, Luke 1:73, Hebrews 6:16-17, and of course Deuteronomy 29:12.

 So what is Christ talking about in Matthew 5:33-36? 

"Again, ye have heard that it hath been said by them of old time, Thou shalt not forswear thyself, but shalt perform unto the Lord thine oaths: but I say unto you, Swear not at all; neither by heaven; for it is God's throne: nor by the earth; for it is his footstool: neither by Jerusalem; for it is the city of the great King. Neither shalt thou swear by thy head, because thou canst not make one hair white or black. But let your communication be, Yea, yea; Nay, nay: for whatsoever is more than these cometh of evil."

This is where we must understand the context!
The Church teaches that what He was speaking against here were frivolous oaths. People had fallen into the habit of making oaths very lightly, and they had even come up with a system of determining whether an oath was binding or not, based on certain formulas, with the obvious intention of being able to make false oaths without any fear of violating the law, as they had misinterpreted it. Christ spoke of this very specifically (Matthew 23:16-22)

Woe unto you, ye blind guides, which say, Whosoever shall swear by the temple, it is nothing; but whosoever shall swear by the gold of the temple, he is a debtor! Ye fools and blind: for whether is greater, the gold, or the temple that sanctifieth the gold? And, Whosoever shall swear by the altar, it is nothing; but whosoever sweareth by the gift that is upon it, he is guilty. Ye fools and blind: for whether is greater, the gift, or the altar that sanctifieth the gift? Whoso therefore shall swear by the altar, sweareth by it, and by all things thereon. And whoso shall swear by the temple, sweareth by it, and by him that dwelleth therein. And he that shall swear by heaven, sweareth by the throne of God, and by him that sitteth thereon"


Finally we should note that Jesus often spoke with very strong hyperbole. We do not take Matthew 5:29-30 literally, the streets are not filled with maimed blind amputees who believe in Christ so strongly that they defiled their own temple of God (their body).
The purpose of this teaching is to make us avoid swearing to do something, without actually seriously considering what we have promised. (For example, do not "promise" to take out the trash later, simply say that you will)
Likewise with regard to the 3rd commandment in this context, St Philaret of Moscow says in his Catechism of the Russian Orthodox Church...


When is God's name taken in vain?
It is taken or uttered in vain when it is uttered in vain and unprofitable talk, and still more so when it is uttered lyingly or irreverently.




What sins are forbidden by the third commandment? ... 5: Perjury... 6: Oath breaking... 7: Breach of vows made to God... 8: Common swearing or thoughtless oaths...




Are not such oaths specially forbidden in holy Scripture?
The Saviour says: I say unto you, Swear not at all, but let your communication be, Yea, yea; Nay, nay: for whatsoever is more than these cometh of evil. Matt 5:34-37.




Does not this go to forbid all oaths in civil matters?
The Apostle Paul says: Men swear by the greater*; and an oath for confirmation is to them an end of all strife. Wherein God, willing more abundantly to show unto the heirs of promise the immutability of his counsel, confirmed it by an oath. (Heb 6:16-17.) Hence we must conclude, that if God himself for an immutable assurance used an oath, much more may we on grave and necessary occasions, when required by lawful authority, take an oath or vow religiously, with the firm intention of not breaking it" (The Longer Catechism of the Orthodox, Catholic, Eastern Church (1839), in Philip Schaff, The Creeds of Christendom. Volume 2: The Creeds of the Greek and Latin Churches (Grand Rapids, Michigan: Baker, 1993 [reprint]), p 528f).



*For men verily swear by the greater: and an oath for confirmation is to them an end of all strife. -Hebrews 6:16


Thanks, Wyrsa. Could you also pinpoint where St Paul says that men swear by the greater ( Ref: para 535 as quoted by you in the Answer ) ?

That's Hebrews 6:16 being referenced by St. Philaret of Moscow

For men verily swear by the greater: and an oath for confirmation is to them an end of all strife.
Thanks, Wyrsa. Read on to Verse 17 : Wherein God, willing more abundantly to shew unto the heirs of promise the immutability of his counsel,  by an oath:

@KadalikattJosephSibichan You really should rephrase your question so it is not confusing. Just because I was able to interpret what you meant to say, is clearly not the normal result (judging by the downvoting). Happy I could help

Thanks, I will try to incorporate Hebrew 6 in the Question, and give it a readable format.

Wyrsa, the Question stands edited. Thanks for providing insights .
